# Why does my like button like all my images when I only liked one image?

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, uikit

I have this collection view with all these images in my VC. When I tap on one of them another VC opens up and I can tap on a button to like the image which is indicated by the button changing its image. The problem Im having is that all the other images are getting changed too. How would I specifically just like the one image I tapped on and not all of them. Here is the code Im working with:

```
 //First VC

     func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "customCell", for: indexPath) as!
    CustomCollectionViewCell

    //shows text
    cell.nameLbl.text = heroes[indexPath.row].localized_name.capitalized
    cell.nameLbl.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true

    //shows images
    let defaultLink = "https://api.opendota.com"
    let completeLink = defaultLink + heroes[indexPath.row].img

    print("This is my\(completeLink)")


    cell.imageView.downloaded(from: completeLink)
    cell.imageView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true


    //shows the num of how many heroes there are
    let heroCount = heroes.count
    howManyHerosLabel.text = String(describing: heroCount)

    return cell
}


func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {



    let completeLink = defaultLink + heroes[indexPath.item].img//this will return the exact string for selected cell

    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let secondViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "secondViewController") as! HeroViewController

    secondViewController.completeLink2 = completeLink
    secondViewController.completeLink3 = heroes[indexPath.item].localized_name.capitalized

    self.present(secondViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)

    print("the title of the image is \(completeLink)")
 }



    //Second VC
    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


    if UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "Change") {

    likedButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "selected_star"), for: .normal)

    }


    //returns image and text that was presssed on in the VC
    heroImageView2.downloaded(from: completeLink2)
    labelForHero!.text = completeLink3


    }



    @IBAction func addToLikes(_ sender: Any) {
    //progressView.isHidden = false

    UserDefaults.standard.set(true, forKey: "Change")
    likedButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "selected_star"), for: .normal)

    }
```

Comment: Show your `cellForItemAt` please.

Comment: I added the code

Answer (score 1):

You need to have unique values to identify if its liked or unliked

```
UserDefaults.standard.set(true, forKey: "Change")
```

For now .. you are checking against change ... once set to true will remain true ...
My suggestion is  to pass `heroes[indexPath.item].img` to other controller and set UserDefault against this value